# PDO query doesnt work but generated SQL runs on PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I am trying to run the following PDO query but it doesn't update the record at all. If I run the code through PHPMyAdmin it runs fine and updates the record.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'general';
$dbpass = 'removed';
$dbname = 'removed';
try {
$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
}catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
$query="UPDATE `soldier_info` SET `soldier_image`= '$soldier_image' WHERE `soldier_id`=" . $_POST['soldier_id'];
echo $query;
$q=$dbo->prepare($query);
$q->execute();
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I don't see any error message echo'd or printed on the page and when I echo $query it shows:

```
UPDATE `soldier_info` SET `soldier_image`= 'http://www.bringingthemhome.co.uk/preview/images/soldiers/soldier1.jpg' WHERE `soldier_id`=4
```

As mentioned the code runs fine through PHPMyAdmin

Comment: "I don't see any error message" - set as a $dbo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: Thanks @reg that showed me that my user didn't have access to update! :) Rookie mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'general';
$dbpass = 'removed';
$dbname = 'removed';

try {
    $dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $q = $dbo->prepare("UPDATE `soldier_info` SET `soldier_image`= :image WHERE `soldier_id`= :id");
    $q->execute(array(":image" => $soldier_image, :id" => $_POST['soldier_id']));
}catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

And make sure $soldier_image is defined.

Comment: Thanks @tanatos I put that in it didnt solve my problem fully but it help in conjunction with reg's comment :) It was a silly error because the user didnt have update permissions! Thanks